ReactJS - Component doesn't update when useState is changed
My father component FatherComponent holds a useState called objectList that contains a list of objects. testComponents is iterated over to generate a list of child components called ChildComponent. FatherComponent contains a button (addComponent) *that adds an object to objectList when clicked, therefore creating a new ChildComponent. Each ChildComponent holds a 'removeComponent' button that allows the current component to be deleted. This button works correctly in updating the objectList but it doesn't trigger a re-render of the father component. Only the addComponent button does. Here's my code:
const FatherComponent = ({data}) => {

    const [objectList, setObjectList] = useState(data.objects)

    //each element of objectList is assigned an incremental unique id when created,
    //the id is used to delete the correct object from objectList
    const removeComponent = (id) => {
        let newObjectList = objectList

        let index = newObjectList.findIndex(object => object.id === id);

        newObjectList.splice(index, 1);

        setObjectList(newObjectList)
    }

    const addComponent = (prevObjects) => {

        setObjectList([...prevObjects, new Object(data.newObjectId)])
        data.newObjectId += 1
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        data.objects = objectList
    }, [objectList, data])

    return (
        <Fragment>

            ...

            <button onClick={() => addComponent(objectList)}>Add Component</button>
                {objectList.map((childComponent) => (
                    <ChildComponent
                        object={childComponent}
                        removeComponent={() => removeComponent(childComponent.id)} />
                ))}
        </Fragment>

}

Keep in mind that it is my interest for the objectList to be part of a big class structure, holding all the information in my tool. That is why you see it updated in useEffect. that is not the only reason. useState is initialized with the values of data on every re-render so it has to be updated. Here is the ChildComponent:
const ChildComponent = ({ object, removeComponent }) => {

    return (

        ...
    
        <button onClick={removeComponent}>Remove Component</button>

        ...

    );
}

I don't understand why the FatherComponent doesn't re-render when removeComponent is called. The function contains a useState setter, shouldn't that trigger a re-render?

@SergeySosunov Yes it does! Thank you, If you want you can publish that as an answer.
